# move code out of onCreate method and into its own class file

Tags: java, android

I have the code below which I am using from an Android java tutorial.

The code is all in the apps main java file onCreate method, and I would like to move the XML processing part to a separate class.

I tried doing this several different ways, but all of them ended up failing horribly and became more cumbersome that they were worth.

So my question is, is there a good/standard way of moving the code out of the main java file and into a separate class?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_xml);
    String stringXmlContent;

    try {
            stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
            myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
          throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
    {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Resources res = activity.getResources();
        XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
        String elType = "mt";
        int counter = 1;
        int mainTopics = 0;
        int subTopics = 0;
        xpp.next();

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
            {
                stringBuffer.append("News Categories");
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("subTopic")) {
                    elType = "st";
                    subTopics += 1;
                } else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mainTopic")) {
                    elType = "mt";
                    mainTopics += 1;
                } else {
                    elType = "";
                }
                //stringBuffer.append("\nSTART_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
            {
                //stringBuffer.append("\nEND_TAG: "+xpp.getName());
            }
            else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
            {
                if(elType.equalsIgnoreCase("st")) {
                    stringBuffer.append("\n         *"+xpp.getText());
                } else {
                    stringBuffer.append("\n " + counter + ") " + xpp.getText());
                    counter+= 1;    
                }
            }
                eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        //stringBuffer.append("\n--- End XML ---");
        stringBuffer.append("\n Total Topics: " + mainTopics + "   Total SubTopics: " + subTopics);
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
```

I got this to work: moving it into another class called readXML like this:

```
        readXML processXml = new readXML();

    try {
            stringXmlContent = processXml.getEventsFromAnXML(this);
            myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I just wrapped the method "private String getEventsFromAnXML" in the new class

like this:

```
public class readXML {

private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)
        ....process XML...
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear, are you trying to move the code with the `getEventsFromAnXML` method to a separate class?

Comment: what exactly that mean? move out code where?? can you rephrase your question?

Comment: sorry...I got it to work.  I edited the original post above.  What I meant was, I wanted to move the method "getEventsFromAnXML" to its own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use abstract context class to do this:

Change the parameter type of your xml parser method to:

```
private String getEventsFromAnXML(Context ctx)
{

  ....
  Resources res = ctx.getResources();
  ....

}
```

And call it from your activity like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

  .....
  ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
  stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(ctx);
  .....

}
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like AsyncTask would be a perfect fit for what you want to do. (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

You can move your processing code to `doInBackground()` and update your `TextView` in the method `onPostExecute()`. Also, you can pass a reference of your `TextView` in the `AsyncTask` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the IDE of your choice allows to do "Refactorings", which allow you to move methods in to other classes, which you can then use.

And yes, extracting methods into other classes is pretty common.